# Primeicons not working for tree component

Tags: css, angular, typescript

Here is my code: https://github.com/d1rtyW0lf/aqp-regroupement

My styles:

```
"styles": [
     "node_modules/primeicons/primeicons.css",
     "node_modules/primeng/resources/primeng.min.css",
     "node_modules/primeng/resources/themes/omega/theme.css",
     "node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css"
],
```

And the loaded result:

[image]

which I would like to be rendered like this:

[image]

I know that Prime replaced font awesome with PrimeIcons. Where can I find the names of each of those icons to test?

Is Fontawesome still required today? The documentation does not suggest that, but most posts dealing with this issue have required it anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to change the font name in tree array.

```
this.files = [
  {
    label: 'Folder 1',
    collapsedIcon: 'pi pi-folder',
    expandedIcon: 'pi pi-folder-open',
...
```

Here icon list available.

https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/icons